Bigquery: Create a temporary external table
According to the GCP official documentation

You can query an external data source in BigQuery by using a permanent table or a temporary table

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-tables#temporary_table_support
However, creating a new table with CREATE TEMPORARY EXTERNAL TABLE table1 gives me the following error:
CREATE TEMP EXTERNAL TABLE is not supported at [1:1]

Is there a way of doing it and I am just doing it wrong or there is no support for this?

External tables are data stored outside of BigQuery’s managed storage, in other words, persistent external data.The Temporary tables are tables that exist only for the duration of your query session. So linking a temporary table to an external data source doesn’t make sense because the temporary table would vanish, leaving the external data reference dangling.
I think the best workaround is to create a regular external table, this way, the table definition persists, so you don’t have to recreate it every time.

I think that in my case it make sense to have a temporary external table that only lasts for the duration of the session. I have a non encrypted data in a file stored and want to hash some PII data before it reaches any bigquery tables. I don't want anyone access this PII information. At the end what I do is create a temporary table with very restrictive access, hash that information, export to a new file and drop the tmp table.
